# Not redirected back to post after logging in on mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, redirection

When I hit "Ask" and then login on the mobile site, I get redirected back to the Ask page once logged in.  Perfect.  But when I log in while viewing a question on the mobile site, I get directed back to the homepage instead of the question.  This is pretty annoying and doesn't match the desktop experience.  Please fix and direct me back to what I was viewing in all cases!

Comment: Repro'ed - we'll get a fix out for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The next build will fix this.

The return behavior after logging in should be identical between the mobile and desktop sites now.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response guys!